# Load web page in PhoneGap app

Tags: url, cordova, iframe, webview

I'm using PhoneGap with AngularJS framework. 
I want to display a web page. I tried to use iframe but scroll isn't working. 
I want to keep this page inside my app and not as a in app browser or external browser.

My app is running on iOS, Android and WP8 both.

Some help please :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think _InAppBrowser_ is more appropriate for this situation. Refer [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).

Comment: Yes but _InAppBrowser_ will do something like [that](http://cl.ly/image/3B0g1A1O0L3q) and I want something like [that](http://cl.ly/image/1k0p3N0F302v)

Comment: ok... We may need changes in config.xml <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>.

Comment: I've got the same result, any ideas?

Comment: To make transparent status bar, check this plugin :  <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" /> . this worked for me. Then for the header section can you please provide code?

Comment: I am using AngularJS, my code :
`.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.navTitle = "Accueil";

        $scope.leftButtons = [];

        $scope.rightButtons = [];

        window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    })`

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadWebView(pid)
    {
    var url = "http://dummysite.com/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/"+pid;
    $("#div_load_page").html('<object data='+url+' class="webview"/>');
  };
```

This is simple jQuery I've applied in my phonegap application which gives me the desired result. Scroll bars are visible and depend on site's responsiveness and size.

[See Result](http://s2.postimg.org/lxtu2amqh/Capture.jpg).